# Пишу Listener портов, выдаёт ошибку Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def execute_remotely(self, command):
    self.connection.send(command)
    return self.connection.recv(1024)

def run(self):
    while True:
        command = input('>> ')
        result = self.execute_remotely(command)
        print(result)
```

Помогите решить в чем проблема, при запуске Listener работает, когда код доходит до строки где нужно ввести команду, после ввода команды (в данном случае DIR) или любой другой, код закрывается с ошибкой:

```
dir
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/new1/listener/listener.py", line 26, in <module>
    my_listener.run()
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/new1/listener/listener.py", line 22, in run
    result = self.execute_remotely(command)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/new1/listener/listener.py", line 16, in execute_remotely
    self.connection.send(command)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str')
```

Comment: `self.connection.send(command.encode())` или с указанием кодировки, если не только английский текст должен передаваться.

Comment: @ insolor лучший, спасибо. Ток у меня вопрос, когда я на основной тачке, ввожу команды от винды, мне в терминале выполнение команды отображается слитно, как написать так, чтобы оно отображалось идентично как в cmd? (например даже выполнение dir)

Comment: Ну это надо смотреть что конкретно выводит. Я вангую, что вам ответ в байтах приходит, вы его как байты и выводите (получается строка вида `b"...."`, переносы строк внутри заэкранированы). Нужно байты в строку декодировать в строку (метод `.decode()` или с указанием кодировки), потом уже эту строку выводить.